# HTML after not displaying after a div

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS (minimised version):

```
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">

footer ul li {
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  color:#aaa;
  font-size:15px;
}

footer div li {
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  color:#aaa;
  font-size:15px;
}

footer ul li:after {
  content:"|";
  margin:0 3px 0 3px;
}

footer div li :after{
  content:"|";
  margin:0 3px 0 3px;
}
    </style>
</head>




<body>

<footer>
  <div>
    <li>############ College, #### Street, ############, ### ###</li>
    <li>Switchboard: ###### ######</li>
  </div>

  <br>

  <ul>  
    <li>&copy; Copyright ##### ###### 2015</li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/terms-conditions') ?>">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/privacy-policy') ?>">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem is, the '|' is not showing after the 'div', but is showing after the 'ul'.

I have tried many different options and searched for hours but cannot find out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can't have a space before `:after`..looks like you have a typo

Comment: Also, `li` **cannot** be children of a `div`...only a `ul`.

Comment: @Paulie_D So simple!!

Comment: You cant do this  `<div><li>###` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spacing problem in the

```
first div li :first
{}
```

which should be

```
first div li:first
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect, you can't have a space before the `:after`

```
footer div li :after{
```

You also have a missing `<ul>` tag here. List items must have a UL, DL or OL parent (in this case, a UL).

```
<footer>
  <div>
    <ul> <!-- add this-->
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4awc0822/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
<div>
    <li>############ College, #### Street, ############, ### ###</li>
    <li>Switchboard: ###### ######</li>
</div>
```

with

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>############ College, #### Street, ############, ### ###</li>
    <li>Switchboard: ###### ######</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div>
    <li>############ College, #### Street, ############, ### ###</li>
    <li>Switchboard: ###### ######</li>
  </div>
```

at this HTML part of your code you are using `<li>` elements but didnt even define a `<ul>`
if u define the  it should do the trick:

```
 <div>
   <ul>
    <li>############ College, #### Street, ############, ### ###</li>
     <li>Switchboard: ###### ######</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wp2apph7/)   try this one..

```
footer div li:last-child:after{
content:"|";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

space after div li: should be footer div li:after. This makes the "|" show up.